# python matplotlib, second y axis coresonded to first one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have altitude presure and temperature in a CSV file.

Now I want to plot the temperature (x-axes) against altitude (y-axes).
On the second Y-Axes there should be the corresponded pressure displayed in an inverted log axes.
[similiar to here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmMU.gif)

This is the code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter


data = genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=";")

# presure (hPa), altitude (m)
altitude, pressure, temperatur = data.T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax,ax2)
    
ax.plot(temperatur, altitude, label='Temperature')
ax.set_xlabel('°C')
ax.set_ylabel('m')
ax.set_ylim(0, 15000)

ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: pressure[pos]))

plt.show()
```

here some data:

```
658.18837;940.56904;22.17028
663.54261;939.99102;22.13224
668.91575;939.41132;22.13249
674.37554;938.82261;22.13454
679.86459;938.23111;22.11198
685.49578;937.62465;22.09777
691.29321;937.00067;22.05775
697.26395;936.35845;22.09801
702.43408;935.80256;21.87262
706.51564;935.3637;21.77721
710.45886;934.93975;21.68197
715.56184;934.3913;21.67625
720.97886;933.80945;21.68942
727.17314;933.14455;21.68583
733.47037;932.46905;21.6334
```

Comment: Does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evIIn.png) what you want?

Comment: not exactly just plot the temperature vs Altitude and vs Pressure (other axis)

Comment: In my picture, the blue line represents `Pressure`, its yaxis is on the left. The red line represents `Altitude`, its yaxis is on the right.

Comment: yes thats true but can we make the blue line invisibel so that the left axis stays an only the red temperature line is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `alpha` parameter to adjust the line's transparency.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt


data = genfromtxt("1.csv", delimiter=";")


# presure (hPa), altitude (m)
altitude, pressure, temperature = data.T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
ax.plot(temperature, altitude, label='Temperature', color='r')
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature(°C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Altitude(m)')


ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Pressure(mb)')
ax2.plot(temperature, pressure, color='b', alpha=0)

fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image]